# What's the time complexity of this algorithm? And Why?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I am stuck by analyzing the time complexity of the following algorithm:

```
def fun (r, k, d, p):
    if d > p:
        return r
    if d = 0 and p = 0:
        r <- r + k
        return r
    if d > 0:
        fun (r, k + 1, d - 1, p)
    if p > 0:
        fun (r, k - 1, d, p - 1)
```

The root call will be `fun (0, 0, n, n)`, and `n` is the size of the problem.

I guess that: The recurrence relation is $ T(n, n) = T(n-1, n) + T(n, n-1)$, which is equivalent to $T(2n) = 2T(2n-1) \iff T(m) = 2T(m - 1)$, and so $O(2^m) \iff O(4^n)$.

Is my analysis correct (I know it's not very complete and exact)? If it does have serious flaw, please point it out or show me a correct and complete proof on the time complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: xando, I encourage you to edit the question to explain why the standard techniques don't work: explain why they fail.  (Cc: @YuvalFilmus)  For instance, do you get a recurrence relation that's hard to solve, and if so, what recurrence do you get?

Comment: In comments with Polyergic, I've realized that the pseudocode is unclear: it's not clear what you mean for the algorithm to do, when both `d>0` and `p>0`.  You don't show what the function returns if we reach the 3rd and 4th if statements.  Did you mean to have a `return` statement after each recursive invocation of `fun`?  (did you mean `fun (r, k + 1, d - 1, p)` to be `return fun (r, k + 1, d - 1, p)`?)  Or did you mean to have a `return` statement at the very end of the function body?  Please edit your pseudocode to clarify and make sure you show what this returns in all possible cases.

Comment: To say it in another way: suppose `d<=p` and `d>0` and `p>0` all hold.  What is supposed to happen?  Does the algorithm make 2 recursive invocations to the function?  Or does it recursively invoke `fun(r, k + 1, d - 1, p)` and then immediately return, without recursively invoking `fun(r, k - 1, d, p - 1)`?  If I take your pseudocode literally, it appears that it makes 2 recursive invocations and then returns with an undefined return value -- but that seems odd and makes me wonder if there's a typo/bug in the pseudocode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only two arguments relevant to asymptotic analysis are $d$ and $p$. These arguments (virtually) satisfy $d,p \geq 0$ and $d \leq p$ (we need to shuffle the logic in the function slightly to get this). At each point in the execution, you take the current pair $(d,p)$ and then recursively call the function with the pairs $(d-1,p),(d,p-1)$, avoiding pairs which invalidate the constraints stated above.

We can picture the resulting call tree as a path starting at $(0,0)$. Each time you decrease $p$, add a / step. Each time you decrease $d$, add a \ step. The condition $d \leq p$ guarantees that you never go below the X axis. Moreover, you have a "budget" of $n$ of each step. The total number of *leaves* in this call tree is exactly the Catalan number $\binom{2n}{n}/(n+1) = \Theta(4^n/n^{3/2})$, and this gives us a lower bound on the running time of the function.

To get an upper bound, note that on the way to each leaf we pass through $2n$ nodes, and this gives an upper bound $2n$ larger than the lower bound, i.e., $\Theta(4^n/\sqrt{n})$.

We have a lower bound of $\Omega(4^n/n^{3/2})$ and an upper bound on $O(4^n/\sqrt{n})$. What are the exact asymptotics? They grow like the total number of paths not crossing the X axis which have at most $n$ steps in each direction. Using [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) we can get an exact expression for this:
$$
\sum_{0 \leq d \leq p \leq n} \frac{p-d+1}{p+1} \binom{p+d}{p}.
$$
It thus remains to estimate this sum asymptotically:
$$
\sum_{0 \leq d \leq p \leq n} \binom{p+d}{p} - \sum_{0 \leq d \leq p \leq n} \frac{d}{p+1} \binom{p+d}{d} = \\
\sum_{0 \leq d \leq p \leq n} \binom{p+d}{p} - \sum_{0 \leq d \leq p \leq n} \binom{p+d}{p+1} = \\
\sum_{p=0}^n \binom{2p+1}{p+1} - \sum_{p=0}^n \binom{2p+1}{p+2} = \\
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{p+1} \binom{2p+2}{p} = 
\Theta\left(\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{4^p}{p^{3/2}}\right) =
\Theta\left(\frac{4^n}{n^{3/2}}\right).
$$

Comment: I really like your geometric approach using these "steps". Is that a common technique? I have not seen it before.

Comment: @AndreasT I wouldn't call it a common technique, indeed normally it doesn't apply. Here the combinatorial interpretation is pretty evident, and it leads one to this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Case by case:

1. **d > p**: *Constant* time
2. **d=0 ∧ p=0**: *Constant* time
3. **d > 0**:  Note that d ≯ p, so we have 0 < d ≤ p, and `fun` recurses on d-1 until d ≯ 0; since p > 0, this is *Linear in d + (case 4)*.
4. **p > 0**: Note that d ≯ 0, so we have d ≤ 0 ≤ p (with d < p), and `fun` recurses on p-1 until p ≯ 0; this is *Linear in p + (one of case 1, 2, or 5)*
5. **d ≤ p < 0**: Undefined; I'm assuming this is *Constant* time

Starting with d = p = n > 0 hits case 3, which is followed by case 4.  If n is a whole number, the final case is 2, otherwise the final case is 5.  The total time for those cases is d+p+1, or 2n+1.

Comment: 2n.  I guess you downvoted because I focused on the reasoning?

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer!  The puzzle now is that you concluded that the running time is $O(n)$, but Yuval concluded that the running time is exponential in $n$.  That's a pretty substantial difference.

Comment: Hmm, I think I took the pseudocode `if`s to be a "do one of these" while @Yuval took them to be "consider each of these in order".  The latter is, of course, what `if`s (without `else`) mean in actual code; I'm used to the former in almost any other context than actual code (including in pseudocode, although usage in pseudocode is inconsistent).

Comment: I see what you mean.  The lack of `return` statements in the latter half of the code makes this pretty confusing.